# How to set up a d8 site as an IDP for Success Factors and KeyedIN?

Tags: single-sign-on, drupal-8, idp

The Drupal8(8.7.5) website has SSO(Single Sign ON) implemented with ADFS. We have used the *SimpleSAMLphp* library(simplesamlphp-1.14.8) and D8 *simplesamlphp_auth* module for this implementation, and the Drupal website is a SP.

We have a requirement to enable SSO with two applications Success Factors and KeyedIN from Drupal8 website, so our D8 website should act as an IDP for these two applications.
Enabled the Identity Provider functionality for SimpleSAMLphp following this [link](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp#section_1)

We are asked to send a “SAML Response” on POST method to Support application url’s.
To generate the SAML Response referred this [link](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php)

Also tried out with the D8 *miniorange_saml_idp* module(non-premium),but we are not able to authenticate with the third party customer support applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Drupal site is presently a Service Provider (SP), not an IdP... with ADFS acting as an IdP?

Why can't you just integrate SuccessFactors and KeyedIN with ADFS?

That would seem to be the easy way to leverage what you have to obtain single sign-on. User visits Drupal site, picks up ADFS session, user visits SuccessFactors/KeyedIN, but already has ADFS session so sees no login page.

Unless what you're trying to build is something more akin to a SAML-SAML proxy, i.e. Drupal acting as an IdP **and** as an SP to "bridge" between the vendor (SP) and ADFS (IdP). This could be achieved by leveraging SimpleSAMLphp as both IdP and SP, see e.g.: https://github.com/cirrusidentity/ssp-proxy-tutorial/blob/master/USE_CASES.md

Comment: .Thanks KellenTried out similar method.How can we pass current Drupal logged in user data?

Comment: I'd approach this by adding a small custom module on top of Drupal that'll read the attribute data (`$attributes = $as->getAttributes();` see [1](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-sp)) from the SimpleSAMLphp session and load those into `$_SERVER` or something like that... though you could certainly approach this in other ways.